# ChartJS in React does not change even if props changes - Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am building a website where the user can select a date(s) and a product(s) and see the relative inventory. The representation of the inventory is made via a table and a chart (using `react-chartjs-2`). I am using React Hooks

The props are sent correctly, however I am not sure why the chart is not upgrading dynamically. It does upgrade the value on the bar, but not the bar itself.

Example: In date `15-11-2019`, the product `Desktop ITG56` has an inventory of `25`.

The user can click on the table and modify the inventory. For example, the user sets the inventory of Desktop ITG56 to 11.

If I console.log the new results, the array containing the inventory is updated. However the bar chart does not decrease. If I hover on it, it shows that inventory 25 is replaced by inventory 11 (so it is good!) but the bar does not decrease.

**Before the user types "11" in the table**

[image]

**After the user types "11" in the table**
[image]

**MyGraph component**

```
import React, {Component,  useState, useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import { Line, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'


function MyChart({results}) {

    let selected_dates = results['selected_dates']
    let products_results = results['selected_products']


    let my_dataset = []

    var i;
    if (products_results) {
        my_dataset = []

        for (i = 0; i < products_results.length; i++) {
            let dataset_dict = {}
            dataset_dict['label'] = products_results[i]['product_name']
            dataset_dict['data'] = products_results[i]['inventory']
            dataset_dict['lineTension'] = 0.5
            dataset_dict['fill'] = false
            dataset_dict['borderColor'] = products_results[i]['color']
            dataset_dict['backgroundColor'] = products_results[i]['color']
            my_dataset.push(dataset_dict)
            console.log(my_dataset)
        }
    }


    let data = {
        labels: selected_dates,
        datasets: my_dataset
    };

    if (results.length === 0) {
        return null
    } else if (results["selected_dates"].length > 1) {
        return(
            <div>
                    <Line
                        data={data}
                        options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true }}
                        redraw
                    />
                </div>
                )
    } else {
        return(
                <div>
                    <Bar
                        data={data}
                        options={{ maintainAspectRatio: true }}
                        redraw
                    />
                </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MyChart;
```

Comment: What kind of state logic has the parent of <MyChart />?

Comment: The `Table` component and `MyChart` component are a child of the `Form`. When the user modifies the `Table`, a handler function is called so that the `Form` is updated with the latest table entities. This works. Since `MyChart` is child of `Form`, and since `Form` resuls update, I do not understand why the bar doe not change.

Comment: I don't see you updating the chart or clearing and redrawing the canvas. That's important.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand that. I am using `redraw`

Comment: I've actually never seen this syntax before and I can't find anything in the chart.js docs. Do you have a source for that?